# Angular basic tutorial do not work with Windows?

Tags: angularjs, git, msbuild

I want to learn Angular so I started with there tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), its really basic but that does not stop me from get ALOT of exception.

I installed latest and stable of every compinent Git, Node and python but when running

```
npm install
```

I got some exceptions, I then reinstalled components to a older specific version(no backward compability here). This got my a couple of steps but yet again other exceptions was thrown like this :

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
>   argets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v12 0') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build
>   tools, either click the Proj ect menu or right-click the solution, and
>   then select "Update VC++ Projects..."

Why would it need MSBuild? Anyway, I changed the config like this

```
npm config set msvs_version 2012
```

And now I get even more exceptions!?, like these :

```
C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  bufferutil.cc
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(336): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(336): error C2059: syntax error : 'using' [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(469): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(469): error C2059: syntax error : 'using' [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(576): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WeakCallbackType' [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(642) : see reference to class template instantiation 'v8::PersistentBase<T>' being compiled
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(637): error C2253: 'PersistentBase<T>' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(844): error C2253: 'Global<T>' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(847) : see reference to class template instantiation 'v8::Global<T>' being compiled
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(852): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(852): error C2059: syntax error : 'using' [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(915): error C2989: 'v8::HandleScope' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(319) : see declaration of 'v8::HandleScope'
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(949): error C2989: 'v8::EscapableHandleScope' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(135) : see declaration of 'v8::EscapableHandleScope'
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(979): error C2989: 'v8::Data' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(74) : see declaration of 'v8::Data'
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(1118): error C2989: 'v8::Script' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(96) : see declaration of 'v8::Script'
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(1559): error C2989: 'v8::StackTrace' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(101) : see declaration of 'v8::StackTrace'
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(1622): error C2989: 'v8::StackFrame' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(100) : see declaration of 'v8::StackFrame'
C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(2031): error C2989: 'v8::Value' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template [C:\Users\bob\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\bob\.node-gyp\4.2.3\include\node\v8.h(108) : see declaration of 'v8::Value'
```

Is it really supose to be this hard to install Angular on a Windows 8.1 computer? Or are my environment faulted in any way?

How do I solve this problem? Have search alot but no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Node/NPM/Angular on 4 differents machines of mine. This is what I've done to make it all work:

- [Visual C++ 2005](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387)
- [Visual C++ 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368)
- [Visual c++ 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
- [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

I don't know why, I've just followed the console erros and all worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is hard. The reason for this is that (dependend on the node modules you install) node-gyp rebuilds things to make them run on the platform, in your case Windows 8.

There are lots and lots of questions how to solve these kind of errors. Prepare yourself to install Python and Visual Studio [like explained here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation).

Good luck! Working with node.js on Linux or OSX is much easier....